# including caption after \includegraphics in latex beamer slides

Tags: beamer, includegraphics

I'm trying to include a caption or source note at the bottom of a slide. For example, I'd like to include the url for the graphic.
http://www.assignmentpoint.com/business/economics/assignment-on-rostows-development-model-and-bangladesh.html

Thank you.

MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{verbatim} %for commenting chunks

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%below removes bottom navigation bars
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

%below removes header 
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} 


\title{International Development}
\subtitle{Lecture 10 - Developmental vs. predatory states}
\author{Instructor}
\institute{University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Rostow development model (1960)}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.72]{Five-Stages-of-Development.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `figure` instead of `center` and insert `\caption{}` inside it.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need to load `graphicx` with beamer

Comment: As an alternative to @Sigur good suggestion you could also just start a new line and write your desired information there.

Comment: @Sigur Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter, done!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is obtained with small changes in your code. Use `figure` instead of `center` and insert `\caption{}` inside it

(as observed by @samcarter, you don't need to load `graphicx` within `beamer` class)

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Rostow development model (1960)}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.72]{Five-Stages-of-Development.jpg}
\caption{insert here}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please feel free to undo my edit, I just removed some unnecessary code (beamer doesn't have floats and figures are centred by default)